# Use .htaccess to hide variables

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url

Ok, so this is relatively straightforward to do in IIS, however I am trying to make sure everything runs on Apache too.

I need to turn `http://domain.com/?page=about` (where `page` is the variable and `about` is the information) into `http://domain.com/about`

I also want all links to automatically be changed (so if the link is for `?page=about` it gets changed to `about`.)

This is probably simpler than I am making it but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're probably going to want to Google mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have, I can get it to work if I use RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L] (as in it works with domain.com/about.    However, I want it to redirect anything that is /?page=$1 to just /$1 such that domain.com/?page=about turns into domain.com/about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I want it to redirect anything that is /?page=$1 to just /$1 such that domain.com/?page=about turns into domain.com/about

Then you'll need to add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That kinda works but it turns the url into /login?page=login  Any idea why?

Comment: @ajnozari sorry, forgot a `?` at the end of the rule's target