# What do I write in .htaccess to hide ?variablename= in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters

My current .htaccess file says:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# new rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?variablename=$1
```

This allows me to type www.mysite.com/somevalue and it works.  But if I click the button to submit a value like VALUE, it turns the above URL to www.mysite.com/somevalue?variablename=VALUE

And if I'm at www.mysite.com it will go to wwww.mysite.com/?variablename=VALUE

I want it to work so when the user submits a value it goes to www.mysite.com/theusersvalue

Comment: Use `POST`, not `GET`. It has nothing to do with `.htaccess`.

Comment: It's an inputbox and when you click submit I want the URL to be `www.mysite.com/whatevertheusertypedintheinputbox`.  But if I use `POST` the URL will just be `www.mysite.com`.  I don't want that.

Comment: What use case is there for this?

Comment: The URL looks better as `.com/value` instead of `.com/?variablename=value`

Comment: Yes, but it's also very unclear for someone reading the URL. A `POST`ed form is even cleaner.

Comment: It's a gematria calculator.  The input is a phrase.  For example www.gematria.com/phrase will display the gematria of "phrase."  I want the gematria for "phrase" to be accessible by typing in gematria.com/phrase OR by typing "phrase" in the inputbox and hitting the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:
[Use .htaccess to hide variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712117/use-htaccess-to-hide-variables)

Add this piece of code on the htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I put RewriteEngine on
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?word=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1? [QSA,L,R=301]` but going to `.com/about` gives 404 error